# Chart.js render problem when routing Angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, chart.js

I have a chart that looks like as expected, nice and smooth, when it is first initialised:

[image]

But if I change to some other route, then change back to the route that contains the chart, the shape of the chart is all weird and jagged:

[image]

What could be the cause of this? I have seen the chart.js prototype methods on https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html, however, I am not sure which to use and where to put them...

Answer (score 0):

From the image it looks like the `lineTension` property (https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/line.html#dataset-properties) got set to 0 somehow, try to set this back to 0.4 or your custom value and call chart.update()

Comment: So I put a method: `test(): void {
    if (this.chart) {
      this.chart.options.elements.line.tension = 0.4;
      this.chart.update();
    }
  }` in the constructor, however the problem still persists

Comment: also if i `console.log(this.chart.options.elements.line.tension)` before running the update it shows it is already at 0.4

Comment: Then I don't know what the problem is, only solution left I can think of is just rerendering the chart